# DataFrame Index Created From Columns

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that I am using TIA to populate data from Bloomberg.  When I look at df.index I see that the data that I intended to be columns is presented to me as what appears to be a multi-index.  The output for df.columns is like this:

Index([u'column1','u'column2'])

I have tried various iterations of reset_index but have not been able to remedy this situation.

1) what about the TIA manager causes the dataframe columns to be read in as an index?

2) How can I properly identify these columns as columns instead of a multi-index?

The ultimate problem that I'm trying to fix is that when I try to add this column to df2, the values for that column in df2 come out as NaT.  Like below:

```
df2['column3'] = df1['column1']

Produces:

df2
column1 column2 column3
1135     32       NaT
1351      43      NaT
35        13      NaT
135       13      NaT
```

Comment: Do you need `df = df.set_index([u'column1','u'column2'])` ?

Comment: No that doesn't seem to help anything.

Comment: Do you mind to edit your question with proper formatting and or read about [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: my fault thank you

Comment: Pandas operations like `df2['column3'] = df1['column1']` automatically align labels. So if the index of `df1` does not match the index of `df2`, then this assignment will place `NaT` or `NaN`s in `df2['column3']`. It's telling you that there are no values in `df1['column1']` corresponding to the index labels in `df2['column3']`.

Comment: that's what I figured as well.  Right now I see that the index seems to be a multi-index in that when I do df.columns I get the following Index([u'column1',u'column2']), how can I reset the index such that u'column2' becomes just a column?

Comment: I can't post the data unfort, but can you help me understand what the 'u' in the index indicates?

Comment: We don't need to see your actual data, just the structure of the data. To that end, you could edit the values. Mainly we need to understand `df1.index` and `df2.index`. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but the value of `df.columns` doesn't seem to be relevant.)

Comment: In Python2 there are `str`s and `unicode`s. `str`s are sequences of bytes, while `unicode`s are sequences of code points. The `u` in `u'column1'` indicates that the object is a `unicode`. Without the `u`, `'column1'` would be a `str`.

Comment: Thanks for help and understanding pls see below: 
```
df.index
Index([u'Jan',u'Feb',u'Mar',u'Apr',u'May'])

df2.index
Index([u'One',u'Two',u'Three',u'Four',u'Five'])
```

Comment: Oh... So you want `Jan` to correspond with `One`, and `Feb` to correspond with `Two`, etc.?

Comment: Correct.  I actually just tried to add a column 'Number' to df and then merge on it but it said that df2 is an empty dataframe..

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it appears `df1` and `df2` have completely different indexes

```
In [396]: df1.index
Out[400]: Index(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'], dtype='object')

In [401]: df2.index
Out[401]: Index(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'], dtype='object')
```

but we wish to assign values from `df1` to `df2`, *preserving order*.

Usually, Pandas operations try to automatically align values based on index (and/or column) labels.
In this case, we wish to ignore the labels. To do that, use

```
df2['columns3'] = df1['column1'].values
```

`df1['column1'].values` is a NumPy array. Since it doesn't have a Index, Pandas simply assigns the values in the array into `df2['columns3']` in order.
The assignment would behave the same way if the right-hand side were a list or a tuple.
Note that this also relies on `len(df1)` equaling `len(df2)`.

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"column1": [1135, 1351, 35, 135, 0], "column2": [32, 43, 13, 13, 0]},
    index=[u"Jan", u"Feb", u"Mar", u"Apr", u"May"],
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"column1": range(len(df1))}, index=[u"One", u"Two", u"Three", u"Four", u"Five"]
)
df2["columns3"] = df1["column1"].values
print(df2)
```

yields

```
       column1  columns3
One          0      1135
Two          1      1351
Three        2        35
Four         3       135
Five         4         0
```

---

Alternatively, you could make the two `Index`s the same, and then `df2["columns3"] = df1["column1"]` would produce the same result (but now because the index labels are being aligned):

```
df1.index = df2.index
df2["columns3"] = df1["column1"]
```

---

Another way to make the `Index`s match, is to reset the index on both DataFrames:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2["columns3"] = df1["column1"]
```

`reset_index` moves the old index into a column named `index` by default (if `index.name` was `None`). Integers (starting with 0) are assigned as the new index labels:

```
In [402]: df1.reset_index()
Out[410]: 
  index  column1  column2
0   Jan     1135       32
1   Feb     1351       43
2   Mar       35       13
3   Apr      135       13
4   May        0        0
```